# Tachograph decryption of DSRC messages with a smartcard

Tags: encryption, smartcard, apdu

I have a problem decrypting DSRC-RTMdata. According to the "COMMISSION IMPLEMENTING REGULATION (EU) 2016/799 of 18 March 2016" I should do it with the PROCESS DSRC MESSAGE command.

How communication with the smartcard (control card) looks like:

1. SELECT tachoG2 - SELECT tachoG2 - 0x00,0xA4,0x04,0x0C,0x06,0xFF,0x53,0x4D,0x52,0x44,0x54

Response: the card responds 0x90,0x00 - correct processing

2. MANAGE SECURITY ENVIRONMENT (MSE : SET AT) - 0x00,0x22,0x41,0xA4,0x0C,0x80,0x0A,0x04,0x00,0x7F,0x00,0x07,0x02,0x02,0x03,0x02,0x02

Response: the card responds 0x90,0x00 - correct processing

3. Sending PROCESS DSRC MESSAGE which contains encrypted data - 0x80,0x2A,0x80,0xB0,0x60 + rtm-data + 0x00

Response: the card responds 0x6A,0x80 - "indicates incorrect parameters in the command data field (also used in case the data objects are not sent in the specified order)"

rtmdata data is correctly because the frame starts with 0x87, 0x41 (L87),0x00 then we have encrypted data and then DSRC security data which start with 0x81,0x10 and then 0x8E,0x08

Does anyone have any experience with this communicating with smartcard (control card) and apdu command sequence?

P.S.
I apologize for the duplication, I found a similar question, unfortunately without any answer:
[tachograph smartcard process dsrc message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221251/tachograph-smartcard-process-dsrc-message)

Comment: Data field size: 0x41 + 2 + 0x10 + 2 + 8 + 2 = 0x5F != 0x60. I think zero at the end shouldn't be part of data, because it's not DER-TLV encoded object.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! When I changing the Data field size to 5F (I tested others too) smartcard returns 0x67 0x00 which means: Incorrect length (invalid Lc or Le)

Comment: So, in the case of T=1 connection protocol you can set Lc to 5F and try different Le instead of 00. I don't believe that 0x60 is correct Lc.

Comment: I iterated within a single byte (0-255) over all possible Lc and Le and all combinations. I was getting errors 0x67 0x00 or 0x6A 0x80 all the time.

Maybe the payload from the tachograph is a problem when I check its length is 0x60 and it should be 0x5F - as you wrote.

RtmData is originally encoded in base64 string maybe decoding introduces error?

in python:
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(decoded_data)
print(len(decoded_data)) # gives 96

Comment: I found this document https://publications.jrc.ec.europa.eu/repository/bitstream/JRC120796/dsrc_can_v1.3_online.pdf page 28 indicates that the length 0x60 is correct

Comment: @nvf thanks for pointing me in the direction to discover the solution. I have posted the solution that worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be useful to someone.

The data actually needs to be shorter and should 5F long as @nvf wrote (thanks for pointing me in the direction to discover the solution) however not the 0x00 at the end was the problem. Decoding the data was failing by the byte with index 67 (which I removed in Python - encoded_data.pop(67))

So in the end, the correct sequence that allows you to decrypt the DSRC-RTMdata using the smartcard (control card) looks like::

1. decode the base64 rtm-data and remove from rtm-data byte with index 67
2. SELECT tachoG2 - SELECT tachoG2 - 0x00,0xA4,0x04,0x0C,0x06,0xFF,0x53,0x4D,0x52,0x44,0x54
3. Sending PROCESS DSRC MESSAGE which contains encrypted data - 0x80,0x2A,0x80,0xB0,0x5F + rtm-data + 0x00

(no need to send MANAGE SECURITY ENVIRONMENT)

In response you get decrypted RTM